# drush installing drupal through root ssh is causing 500 internal server error

Tags: drush, installation

I have installed the drupal 7 using the root ssh user. The overall installation process seems ok within ssh. I have even downloaded and enabled the modules through drush. But when I tried to open the site on browser its throwing 500 internal server error.

I used the same process with out any errors when I grant a jailed shell access to the hosting account and login through their cpanel id in ssh.

But for the ease I want to install drupal through root ssh so I don't have to open multiple putty windows to manage multiple accounts.

Comment: Check the owner & group of your files. If the owner and group are root then the web server won't be able to read them.
Also check your server logs for errors that might be helpful.

Comment: I posted this issue to my host and he replied " I see that a majority of the content is owned by root and permissions appear to be way off. We have a permissions script I can run to get all your owners and permissions ironed out. This may resolve the issue. " I have requested him to share the script so I can resolve the issue in future. Posting his reply as an answer so others can be benefited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Matt C from Known Host who helped me resolving this issue. Sharing his reply below so others can be benefited.

> I've run the fix permissions script and it looks like all files and
>   directories are set as they should be. You can find the script in
>   /public_html/fixperms.sh. I've also provided you with a link for
>   fixpermissions:
>
> http://boomshadow.net/tech/fixes/fixperms-script/

Comment: Wow, that script sure it comprehensive. Overkill for this situation I would say but good that you got it fixed.